# How to change output type based on parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a function (several actually) that write output (using Write-Output). Today, the functions all rely on a having a $logpath defined and they output to a text file. In the fewest lines possible, I would like to configure the option to output to the screen if the user wants to (or if $logpath is not specified).

The code below doesn't work, but is an example of what I have in mind. What's the best way to achieve my goal?

```
Function Do-Stuff {
    Param (
        [string]$OutputType
    )

    If ($OutputType -eq 'Host') {
        $out = 'Write-Host'
    }
    Else {
        $out = 'Out-File -FilePath C:\test\log.txt -Append'
    }

    Write-Output ("You are inside the Do-Stuff function.") | $out
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$out = 'Write-Host'` -> `$out = {Out-Host}`, `$out = 'Out-File -FilePath C:\test\log.txt -Append'` -> `$out = {Out-File -FilePath C:\test\log.txt -Append}`, `| $out` -> `| Invoke-Command $out`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting here. When I set $out as (for example): 

`$Out = '& | write-host'`

I get the following error:

**Invoke-Expression : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.**

Comment: I do not say anything about `Invoke-Expression` in my comment. I use `Invoke-Command` not `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: Ah. I was working on Invoke-Expression just before I read your reply, so I was expecting that cmdlet. I'm thrown off by your "->". If I do this: `$out='Write-Host'`, then run `Write-Output ("In the function.") | Invoke-Command $out`, I get an error **Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.**. If I run the command like this `Write-Output ("In the function.") | Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$out}`, then the words "Write-Host" are output to the screen, instead of the actual message.

Comment: `$out` should be `ScriptBlock`: `$out = {Out-Host}`, not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Do-Stuff {
    Param (
        [switch]$WriteHost
    )

    $message = Write-Output ("The function is doing stuff.") 
    If ($WriteHost -or ($logPath -eq $null)) {Write-Host $message} Else {$message | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to output something to the user and to a file is obviously [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx). However, that will always create output both ways, so it's not really configurable the way you want.

I would argue that the best way to go about this is to replace your `$out` variable with an actual logging function that reads input from the pipeline.

```
function Write-Log {
  [Cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [string]$Message
  )
  ...
}
```

You can control output for instance by checking if a logfile is defined in a (script-)global variable:

```
if ($script:Logfile) {
  $Message | Add-Content $script:Logfile
} else {
  Write-Host $Message
}
```

or make each output method depend on a different variable:

```
if ($script:Logfile) {
  $Message | Add-Content $script:Logfile
}
if ($script:WriteToConsole) {
  Write-Host $Message
}
```

You could also use additional parameters on the function:

```
function Write-Log {
  [Cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(...)]
    [string]$Message,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]Logfile = './default.log',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Console
  )
  ...
}
```

or any combination of the above.

For logging I'd probably prefer global variables, though. That way you can define all your logging settings in one place at the top of your script (even make the values depend on script parameters) and simply use

```
... | Write-Log
```

indiscriminately whereever you want something logged in your code.

Also, whenever you need to change something about the way your logging works, you just need to modify the `Write-Log` function without having to touch the rest of the code.

Comment: Great suggestion and I think I will use it in the future. In this case, I ended up handling it a bit differently. I'm going to post what I ended up using, separately.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old question, but I couldn't find an answer I liked. The solution I came up with was to override the Out-File cmdlet with a filter.

```
function Export-Stuff {
    param([string] $FilePath)

    if (-not $FilePath) { filter Out-File { $_ } }

    @('one','two','three') | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath
}
```

```
PS> Export-Stuff
one
two
three
PS> Export-Stuff -FilePath 'output.txt'
PS> Get-Content 'output.txt'
one
two
three
```